# Sweet Alert 2 and javascript:How do i make a Sweet alert button that sends me to a certain webpage when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert, sweetalert2

My code so far:

```
swal({ 
    title: 'Successfully Registered!', 
    text: "Do you want to go to the Log In page?", 
    type: 'success', 
    showCancelButton: true, 
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6', 
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33', 
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, send me there!' 
    }, 
    function(){ 
       window.location.href= "http://example.com"; 
    }
);
```

For some reason the window.location.href is not working and i tried using only location.href and if(isConfirm) etc.

What should i do?

JSFiddle:**https://jsfiddle.net/2dz868kd/**

Comment: you should upload code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so user can see demo and can make changes there.

Comment: I did, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you can make it with [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io):

```js
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Successfully Registered!',
    text: 'Do you want to go to the Log In page?',
    icon: 'success',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, send me there!'
 }).then(function(result) {
   if (result.isConfirmed) {
     location.assign("https://stackoverflow.com/")
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

SweetAlert2 documentation: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Please note that SweetAlert2 and SweetAlert are two different projects. SweetAlert2 uses ES6 Promises.

Comment: Dude you have no idea how much i love you! I spent way too much time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use to redirect on click (OK)

```
<script>
sweetAlert({title: 'Error',text: 'Invalid OTP',type: 'error',onClose: function(){
        window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
}});
</script>
```